# Sort a list of dictionaries using lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've got a list made from a dictionary that has the structure:

```
l = [('name1', {'prop1' : 1, 'prop2': 2}), ('name2', {'prop1' : 1, 'prop2': 2})]
```

I want to sort the list based on the values of one of the properties, basically:

compare l[**0**][1]['prop1'] to l[**1**][1]['prop1'] and so on. How would I do this with a simple lambda function. I thought it would be:

```
l.sort(key = lambda x : [x][1]['prop1'])
```

But that throws out of range errors.

Comment: `[x]` is a list of length 1. You probably mean to write just `x`: `lambda x: x[1]['prop1']`

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yeah, they're all of length 2: the name, the dictionary

Comment: @Brian Oh, yeah, you're right! Silly me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Slight nit: you have a list of tuples, not a list of dictionaries. You want to sort those tuples based on part of the dictionary that is the tuple's second component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [('name1', {'prop1' : 2, 'prop2': 2}), ('name2', {'prop1' : 1, 'prop2': 2})]
print(sorted(l,key=lambda x: x[1]["prop1"]))
```

Output:

```
[('name2', {'prop1': 1, 'prop2': 2}), ('name1', {'prop1': 2, 'prop2': 2})]
```

You can also use `sort()` as follows:

```
l = [('name1', {'prop1' : 2, 'prop2': 2}), ('name2', {'prop1' : 1, 'prop2': 2})]
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]["prop1"])
print(l)
```

You will get the exact same output

Comment: It's a lot more helpful to also say _why_ your answer works than just "here's the answer".

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Well, It was a mistyped function, I didnt think there was a need to explain that details, but noted. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hello! Questions that are caused by typos are off-topic on StackOverflow and should be closed, not answered. Answering off-topic questions [is considered harmful to the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions), and [can attract downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions).

Comment: @Bria Noted, I will say however that I have not saw that question as a typo- until I answered it and double checked (I thought the usage of sort instead of sorted was somehow the problem). In any case thanks for the feedback.